# FilleNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, file-not-found

I've been looking everywhere to a solution to this problem but for some reason, nothing works. I am writing a script to convert midi files to wav files using a python library called midi2audio. The script is located in the same directory as all of the midi files and is trying to create and populate a directory on the desktop.

I get the following error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

The code is below:

```
from midi2audio import FluidSynth
import os

files = [file for file in os.listdir('./') if '.mid' in file]
target_dir = 'C:\\Users\\Arham\\Desktop\\GuitarWavs'

print(os.getcwd())

if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
    print("Creating directory: " + target_dir)
    os.mkdir(target_dir)

print("Converting files...")
for file in files:
    fs = FluidSynth()
    print(file)
    fs.midi_to_audio(file, target_dir+'\\'+file[0:file.index('.mid')]+'.wav') #error here

print('Convertion complete!')
```

The list "files" contains all of the correct filenames and os.getcwd() returns the directory the midi files and script are in. I am especially confused because as far as I can see the path passed to the function trying to find and open that file is correct.

For clarity the directory structure is:

```
Desktop
----FilewithMidis
--------script.py
--------midi files
----GuitarWavs (destination folder)
```

I have tried: giving the explicit path to the file ("C:/Users/.."), using ./file to reference it, using just the filename, using os.path.join to join the path with the filename.

I seriously appreciate any help with this! Thank you!

**EDIT**
Stack trace below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "miditowav.py", line 27, in <module>
    fs.midi_to_audio(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),file), target_dir+'\\'+file[0:file.index('.mid')]+'.wav')
  File "C:\Users\Arham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\midi2audio.py", line 46, in midi_to_audio
    subprocess.call(['fluidsynth', '-ni', self.sound_font, midi_file, '-F', audio_file, '-r', str(self.sample_rate)])
  File "C:\Users\Arham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 323, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\Arham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Arham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I'm starting to think its a problem with fluidsynth, I've heard something about having to add it to my Path variable but I don't know where it's installed as I used pip.

Comment: can you paste the full stacktrace?

Comment: Post the full output of the script.

Comment: Added traceback